# Remote desktop settings not working (Local Resources --> Keyboard --> Apply Windows Key Combinations --> On the remote computer)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop, cmd.exe, windows-10-v1803

I have received a new work laptop and the setting below is not working any longer. I use the Windows key + r key to open Powershell and the cmd prompt hundreds of times a day and my ability to do that now causes the run prompt to open on my laptop, rather than the server I am logged into (with expansion to full screen) and it's become quite a headache. I've tried setting the local resources setting to "on the remote computer" and to "only when using full screen" .

When I use control + alt + escape it opens the task manager on my laptop instead of the server I am remoting into. Alt + tab will bring up my desktop programs to cycle through instead of the server programs.

Is there a place in the registry I can verify the GUI RDP setting is not being overridden? Or possibly a group policy setting? In the default.rdp file, keyboardhook:i:1 is set.
[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity.  What does `ALT+HOME` do?  Are you actually running 1803?

Comment: @Ramhound it is the same behavior as if you clicked on the Windows start menu icon

Comment: As it should have, as that is the combination for it, while connected to a remote desktop. Can you try the "only while full screen" wondering if just toggling the option will make it work.

Comment: @Ramhound I have tried setting it to full screen and then back to on the remote computer, however the behavior stays the same. I'm wondering if it is due to a program running on the laptop that demands foreground when triggered like Skype as an example?

Comment: You should try a minimal boot configuration to rule that possibility out.